# Why is EOFException not thrown in this code (IDE Eclipse)?

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code, and Eclipse reported at the catch block that the EOFException is never thrown in the try block.

I tried to put these two lines:

```
String suit = null;
String rank = null;
```

in the try block, the error at the catch block disappeared.

I also tried to put these two lines:

```
char s = suitString2Char(suit);
char r = rankString2Char(rank);
```

in the try block, the error at the catch block disappeared.

But when I put entire code body in the try block, same error occurred again.

```
public static Card read2(BufferedReader in) throws EOFException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
    String suit = null;
    String rank = null;

    try {

        int i = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {

            suit = i == 0 ? input.next() : suit;
            rank = i == 1 ? input.next() : rank;
            i++;
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        throw new EOFException();
    }   

    char s = suitString2Char(suit);
    char r = rankString2Char(rank);

    if (isValidSuit(s)
            && isValidRank(r)) {

        return new Card(s, r);
    } else {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error disappears because there are other errors that prevent the catch block error to be detected. You can't expect the compiler to show you each and every error there is in the code at once. What exactly is the question, BTW?

Comment: And when you have a correct syntax then there is nothing that would throw that exception in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly:**
The error disappears, because you create code that does not compile, when you do the edits you suggested.

**Secondly:**

[`Scanner.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) does not throw an EOFexception. It throws

```
@throws NoSuchElementException if no more tokens are available
@throws IllegalStateException if this scanner is closed
```

which are [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)s instead of [`EOFException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) which is a so called "checked exception".

The compiler handles them differently when complaining about errors.

> **Checked exceptions** need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.
>
> **RuntimeException** and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo. I did use throw keyword.